# How many "prime" rectangle tilings are there?

Tags: geometry, tiling, rectangles, oeis, dissection

Given two tilings of a rectangle by other rectangles, say that they are equivalent if there is a bijection from the edges, vertices, and faces of the tilings which preserves inclusion. For instance, the following two tilings are equivalent (some corresponding vertices colored):

[image]

The number of non-equivalent rectangle tilings with $k$ tiles is given at [A049021](https://oeis.org/A049021) in the OEIS.

Say that a tiling of a rectangle by $k$ other rectangles is *prime* if the only sub-rectangles in the tiling are individual tiles and the whole set.

Here are the unique prime tilings for $k=1,2,5$ up to equivalence:

[image]

With some casework, one can verify that there are no prime tilings for $k=3,4,6$.

For all $k\ge 7$, there are at least two prime tilings. One follows the pattern shown below:

[image]

The other proceeds in a spiral pattern (in fact this construction yields the $k=5$ solution too):

[image]

It is not hard to check that these two constructions are distinct for all $k$.

**How many non-equivalent prime tilings are there with k rectangles?**

When $k=7$, I have verified that the above two constructions are the only ones possible, but the casework was extensive and I think approaches for $k$ beyond $9$ or $10$ will require new methods or computer-aided searches to be tractable.

This sequence starts $1,1,0,0,1,0,2,\ge2,\ge2,\ldots$. Even accounting for a possible initial term in the case $k=0$ and the possibility that I have missed a solution for $k=7$, there are no matches in the OEIS. I have started a draft for a new sequence, but I would like to be able to compute substantially more terms than this (and confirm my existing results) before adding anything. For comparison, [A053740](https://oeis.org/A053740) gives the analogous sequence for prime dissections of a triangle into smaller triangles.

Some related discussion is at [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mathriddles/comments/bgilmu/distributing_a_rectangular_inheritance/) on /r/mathriddles.

**Edit:** After a laborious manual classification, I believe there are exactly $6$ prime tilings in the $k=8$ case:

[image]

(Note that the horizontal symmetry of the example in the center of the second row is merely for visual appeal; the "heights" of either the SW or the SE rectangles could be varied without affecting equivalence.)

**Edit 2021-02-15:** These tilings are described in [*Tiling Rectangles With Rectangles*](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/82_04_tiling.pdf) (Chung et al., 1982), where they are called *simple* tilings. In the article, it is remarked that there are at least $c\cdot 2^{n/7}$ "essentially different" simple tilings with $n$ rectangles for some $c>0$ (and presumably only for $n\ge 7$?). It is also stated without proof that the number is bounded above by $20000^n$ given "a rather natural definition of equivalence". So the sequence grows exponentially, but it seems that the rate at which it does so is not very well pinned down.

Comment: I have found a third solution for $k=8$, shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/qmxx7jk.png); I believe this construction generalizes to all even integers greater than $8$ as well.

Comment: Such a cool problem! At the risk of asking a stupid question: is it clear that being prime is invariant under equivalence? If so, the abstract in the first paper cited on the OEIS page you mention claims that they have an algorithm for generating all size-$n$ tilings. I presume that, once you have these tilings, it should not be too hard to let a computer check by brute force which ones are prime. Given the rapid growth in the number of tilings I wouldn't be surprised if there are many more prime tilings you didn't catch by hand.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer: Good question! I confess that this is the first time I've tried to formally prove that statement, but I think it's not too difficult to show (and if it fails, then I must have chosen the wrong formal definition to capture my intuition - I think the problem would still be well-defined with the "right" notion of equivalence). Here’s a way of expressing the property that some rectangles form a larger rectangle purely in the language of vertex/edge/face inclusion (too long for this comment):

Comment: Fix a set $S$ of rectangles. Say that an edge is on the border of $S$ if it is contained in a side of exactly one rectangle in $S$. Say that a vertex is a *border vertex* if it lies on a border edge. Say that a border vertex is a *convex corner* if it is the corner of a rectangle in $S$, and does not lie on any other rectangles in $S$. Then I claim that a set $S$ has exactly $4$ convex corners if and only if the union of its pieces is a rectangle.

Comment: To be more precise about my assumptions here, I am allowing us to talk about the edge between two vertices on a rectangle even when that edge is not a full side, so that we can capture notions of two rectangles partially overlapping on their edges. I am also assuming that we associate to each rectangle the vertices which form its corners. (I think both of these extra pieces of data could be removed from the proof with a little care, though.)

Comment: Looks like the lower-middle solution in $k=8$, together with $k=5$, starts another infinite family in increments of $3$.

Comment: @Joffan's idea lets you add 3 tiles to almost any tiling in various ways.