# Partitioning a rectangle or tiling it with rectangles

Tags: combinatorics

Can we count or even recursively construct all ways to tile or partition a rectangle with rectangles? Many other questions ask either of two things none of which I am after:

1. Partitioning a rectangle by vertical or horizontal lines, like in [Number of ways to partition a rectangle into n sub-rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1116/121890).
2. Tiling a rectangle with some prescribed tiles.

My question pertains to all the ways to partition a rectangle such that all partitions are rectangles in itself. I think (1) above does not cover this because of
[image]
for which I think there is no way to create it incrementally by adding straight lines that partition the original or a sub-rectangle.

So let me try to describe which partitions I would like to count and ideally construct:

1. An outer rectangle shall be partitioned into rectangles.
2. The size of the outer or the inner rectangles is not important, so shifting a common side of inner rectangles does not create a new configuration as long as the size is not zero. (I might be missing corner cases here.)
3. Whether mirroring (flipping) or rotational symmetries shall count separately, I don't mind. Whatever is easier to describe.

I suspect that up until 4 inner rectangles, the result is the same as described in the question cited above, but my drawing shows that latest from 5 inner rectangles, the solutions are no longer the same.

Comment: Here is a question that deals with the types of partitions _not_ handled by the one you linked to (such as your example): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008337/how-many-prime-rectangle-tilings-are-there

Comment: Great link, thanks. Afaikt without reading the paper, https://oeis.org/A049021 seems to be a partial answer to my question.

Comment: That is a nice find; you should add it as an answer. I looked through the database quite a bit without finding it.

Comment: Huuh? That oeis link is right in the question you linked :-)

Comment: So it is... ‍♂️